# pixijs text is cutted

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm trying to draw text in pixijs app stage and the text is cut off a bit. See the screenshot below.

[image: "NAGITTO" stylized text, cut off at the start and end]

I've tried to put it inside container but I can't fix it.

```js
const style = new PIXI.TextStyle({
    fontFamily: 'Bangers',
    fontSize: 256,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fill: ['#ffa512', '#ff9e00'], // gradient
    stroke: '#fff',
    strokeThickness: 5,
    dropShadow: true,
    dropShadowColor: '#000000',
    dropShadowBlur: 4,
    dropShadowAngle: Math.PI / 6,
    dropShadowDistance: 2,
});

const richText = new PIXI.Text('Nagitto', style);
richText.x = 50;
richText.y = 250;

app.stage.addChild(richText);
```

No exceptions.
I'm using a font from google fonts.

Answer (score 3):

Use padding property inside style.

```
padding: 5,
```

I suggest you can use https://pixijs.io/pixi-text-style/# to dynamically create text with a preview.

Answer (score 0):

The text is hardly cut from the code you wrote to create it. In my experience, this is only happening when there is a mask on the stage. 
Please show the code for your container where you add the text in.